# First capturing group matching differently

Tags: regex

This is my regular expression which has three capture groups:

```
(.*)([0-9])([A-X]).*
```

However I am getting different group1 match for these two strings:

**String1:**

```
ERICB7LTMC_01
1: [0,5] ERICB
2: [5,6] 7
3: [6,7] L
```

**String2:**

```
OMXDIV7_6TS
1: [0,8] OMXDIV7_
2: [8,9] 6
3: [9,10] T
```

I am not sure why the group1 match in string2 is not OMXDIV. I would really appreciate if someone could explain this matching behaviour.

The regexplanet link for this test: http://fiddle.re/vqayb6

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to get the shortest match up to the first capturing group, you need a lazy matching `(.*?)` and add the `_` to the `A-X` range: `(.*?)([0-9])([A-X_]).*`

Comment: What are exact requirements?

Comment: Your regex is kind of a dot-star soup: it maches everything (.*) then tries to fulfill your other requirements: a number and a char from A-X and everything else (or nothing). For your second string, the first expressions matches everything, then looks for the *first* number when going back (which is the `6`), then looks for a character (which is the `T`) - bingo, an overall match succeeded, no further questions asked. Do it as @WiktorStribiżew said (using a lazy quantifier) or be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you require a number followed by a letter in the range `A-X` with `([0-9])([A-X])`. As `_` (OMXDIV7**_**6TS) is not in the range `A-X` the first match is `OMXDIV7_`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's see what your regex rule actually means.

**Your Regex**: `(.*)([0-9])([A-X]).*`

**Explanation**:

1. `(.*)`: `.` is a **`wildcard`** meta character which matches **any** character except a newline `\n`. You have used `*` which is a *repetition metachracter* matching `0` or `many` often called `greedy` search.
2. `([0-9])`:  Will match **one** digit ranging from `0` to `9`.
3. `([A-X])`: Will match **one** character ranging from `A` to `X`.
4. `.*`: Will match **zero** or **many** characters.

And now your problem.

**Text**: OMXDIV7_6TS

As the group1 is searching for **everything character**, `(.*)` itself will match the whole string `OMXDIV7_6TS`. But then regex engine starts to **backtrack** from the end and look for the matches for group2.

In this process it backtracks till `_` because that's the last character **fitting** in group1 and not found in group2 ( `([0-9])` ) which are only numbers.

That's why regex engine matches `OMXDIV7_6TS` as whole string. While backtracking it reaches `OMXDIV7_`and says **"*Okay `_` is also in group1 but `6` is suited for group2 so I will match group1 till here.*"**

[Regex101 debugger](https://regex101.com/r/kA9pW2/1) is great for understanding whole search.

Comment: *[Regex101 debugger](https://regex101.com/r/kA9pW2/1) is great for understanding whole search.* would be a good comment, why duplicate regex101 work? Instead, you could vote for a dupe "What does this regex mean".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: My intent was not to duplicate regex101's work but as it is evident that the OP is a novice in regex, I explained how  the backtracking works and gave a pointer to understanding more about this process.

Answer (score 0):

As @Thomas addressed, your `regex` is looking for a number `([0-9])` followed by a character in any of `[A_X]`, so `7_` (number `7` followed by a special character `_`) is not a matching entry here...

You can use the below one for the expected behaviour...

```
([A-Z]*).*([0-9])([A-X]).*
```

I.e:

For String-1: **ERICB7LTMC_01**

```
>>> re.findall('([A-Z]*).*([0-9])([A-X]).*', 'ERICB7LTMC_01')
[('ERICB', '7', 'L')]
```

For String-2: **OMXDIV7_6TS**

```
>>> re.findall('([A-Z]*).*([0-9])([A-X]).*', 'OMXDIV7_6TS')
[('OMXDIV', '6', 'T')]
```